# Обьединение двух ArrayList по условию

Tags: java, arraylist

Есть два листа

```
List<Report> ReportTrue, 
List<Report> ReportFalse,
```

В одном элементы такие: 01  True (может быть несколько, 01 - это как будто месяц, true это их булевое поле), в другом 01 False (тоже может быть несколько или один)

Не могу додумать как их объединить в другой лист, чтобы был такой порядок

```
 01 True
 01 True
 01 False
 02 True
 02 False
```

и т.д

Сначала тру одного месяца потом фолс этого же месяца и т.д.

```java
public List<Report> monthlyReportForUser(List<Report> ReportTrue, List<Report> ReportFalse) {

    List<Report> ReportListForUser = new ArrayList<>();
        
    int size = ReportTrue.size() + ReportFalse.size();
        
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            
        if (ReportTrue.get(i).isExpense().ismouth() {
            ReportListForUser.add(ReportTrue.get(i));
        }
    }
        
    return monthlyReportListForUser;
}
```

Comment: объединяйте как хотите, а потом отсортируйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Списки можно объединить просто используя конструктор / метод [`List::addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) и компаратор для сортировки сначала по месяцу, затем по значению true/false (так как false < true, для задания обратного порядка нужно использовать `Comparator.reverseOrder`):

```java
List<Report> total = new ArrayList<>(reportTrue);
total.addAll(reportFalse);
total.sort(Comparator.comparing(Report::getMonth)
    .thenComparing(Report::isTrue, Comparator.reverseOrder()) // true before false
);
System.out.println(total);
```

или же используя Stream API `Stream::concat` + `Stream::sorted` и аналогичный компаратор:

```java
List<Report> merged = Stream.concat(reportTrue.stream(), reportFalse.stream())
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Report::getMonth)
                .thenComparing(Report::isTrue, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(merged);
```

---

Есть ещё вариант с "алгоритмическим" слиянием через циклы, при *обязательном* условии, что оба списка уже отсортированы.

Здесь поочередно инкрементируются индексы в обоих списках:

```java
List<Report> looped = new ArrayList<>();
int t = 0;
int f = 0;
int n = listTrue.size() + listFalse.size();
int k = 0;
while (k < n) {
    boolean trueFound = false;
    while (t < listTrue.size() && (f == listFalse.size() || listTrue.get(t).getMonth() <= listFalse.get(f).getMonth())) {
        looped.add(listTrue.get(t++));
        k++;
        trueFound = true;
    }
    if (trueFound) t--;

    while (f < listFalse.size() && (t == listTrue.size() || listFalse.get(f).getMonth() <= listTrue.get(t).getMonth())) {
        looped.add(listFalse.get(f++));
        k++;
    }
    if (trueFound) t++;
}
```

Comment: Удивительно, но работает с первого раза . Супер

Comment: а если изменить условие  true before false  на false before true ? реверс уже не подходит? поставил naturalOrder вроде сортирует, правильно сделал?

Comment: Если речь о компараторах, достаточно было просто его убрать: `total.sort(Comparator.comparing(Report::getMonth).thenComparing(Report::isTrue));` так как `naturalOrder` используется по умолчанию.

Comment: тут всплыла подробность, я даже не знаю как это реализовать , 01 тру 01 фолс . Я сортировал что сначала тру потом фолс . В итоге оказалось если сумма фолса больше то она будет выше тру, или наоборот  и это в рамках каждого месяца

Comment: total.get().getSum()  -  сумма

Comment: задайте другой вопрос, эта проблема существенно отличается от указанной в первоначальном вопросе.